# Query DynamoDB in Java

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

How do you query/scan a DynamoDB table using only the primary key? The only way I have been able to return results from the table is the code below, where I set the primary key `Id` and add a `Condition` using the sort key `Date`.

Is there any way to query the table without supplying a `RangeKeyCondition`?

```
DynamoDataObject data = new DynamoDataObject();
data.setId(userId);

Condition rangeKeyCondition = new Condition()
    .withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.BEGINS_WITH)
    .withAttributeValueList(new AttributeValue().withS("2018"));

DynamoDBQueryExpression queryExpression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression()
    .withHashKeyValues(data)
    .withRangeKeyCondition("Date", rangeKeyCondition)
    .withConsistentRead(false);

PaginatedList<DynamoDataObject > result = AWSProvider.getInstance().getDynamoDBMapper().query(DynamoDataObject.class, queryExpression);
Log.d(TAG, "PaginatedList length: " + result.size());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. You do not have to include the `withRangeKeyCondition`:

```
DynamoDataObject data = new DynamoDataObject();
data.setId(userId);

DynamoDBQueryExpression queryExpression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression()
    .withHashKeyValues(data)
    .withConsistentRead(false);

PaginatedList<DynamoDataObject > result = AWSProvider.getInstance().getDynamoDBMapper().query(DynamoDataObject.class, queryExpression);
Log.d(TAG, "PaginatedList length: " + result.size());
```